# How is the itab struct actually having a list of function pointers?

Tags: go, internals

Researching the interface value in go - I found a great (maybe outdated) [article](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces) by Russ Cox.
According to it:

> The itable begins with some metadata about the types involved and then becomes **a list of function pointers**.

The implementation for this itable *should be* the one from src/runtime/runtime2.go:

```golang
type itab struct {
    inter *interfacetype
    _type *_type
    hash  uint32 // copy of _type.hash. Used for type switches.
    _     [4]byte
    fun   [1]uintptr // variable sized. fun[0]==0 means _type does not implement inter.
}
```

First confusing thing is - how is an array - variable sized?
Second, assuming that we have a function pointer at index 0 for a method that satisfies the interface, where could we store a second/third/... function pointer?

Comment: The compiled code and runtime access `fun` as if the field is declared `fun [n]uintpr` where `n` is the number of methods in the interface.   The second method is stored at `fun[1]`, the third at `fun[2]` and so on.  The Go Language does not have a variable size array feature like this, but the compiled code and runtime are not constrained by features of the language.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is this magic somewhere to be found in runtime's code? Managed to find the code for populating the list from the *itab init method -> `*(*unsafe.Pointer)(add(unsafe.Pointer(&m.fun[0]), uintptr(k)*sys.PtrSize)) = ifn` (before the changes from commit 8d86ef22 which obscure a little what is done).

Comment: Maybe [this commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/1dd0163ce3993192171149c9ee7e4cd538b36b8a) - line 100 in iface.go makes the most sense.

Comment: The expression `*(*unsafe.Pointer)(add(unsafe.Pointer(&m.fun[0]), uintptr(k)*sys.PtrSize)) = ifn` is the same as `m.fun[k] = ifn` in a hypothetical world where `m.fun` is a variable size array with length > k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiled code and runtime access `fun` as if the field is declared `fun [n]uintpr` where `n` is the number of methods in the interface. The second method is stored at `fun[1]`, the third at `fun[2]` and so on. The Go Language does not have a variable size array feature like this, but [unsafe](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe) shenanigans can be used to simulate the feature.

Here's how [itab is allocated](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/f03ab0e0140544abfb10698b9171a91f9dd9c7a5/src/runtime/iface.go#L67):

```
m = (*itab)(persistentalloc(unsafe.Sizeof(itab{})+uintptr(len(inter.mhdr)-1)*goarch.PtrSize, 0, &memstats.other_sys))
```

The function `persistentalloc` allocates memory.  The first argument to the function is the size to allocate. The expression `inter.mhdr` is the number of methods in the interface.

Here's [code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/f03ab0e0140544abfb10698b9171a91f9dd9c7a5/src/runtime/iface.go#L67) that creates a slice on the variable size array:

```
methods := (*[1 << 16]unsafe.Pointer)(unsafe.Pointer(&m.fun[0]))[:ni:ni]
```

The expression `methods[i]` refers to the same element as `m.fun[i]` in a hypothetical world where `m.fun` is a variable size array with length > `i`.  Later code uses normal slice syntax with `methods` to access the variable size array `m.fun`.

Comment: So the only point of doing this kind of shenanigans is to allow itab be contiguous in memory including methods pointers number of which can vary? Is this just an optimization to avoid double indirection and be cache friendly?